# use characteristic functions to find what the sequence of distributions N(0,n) converge to

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given the following theorem (that can be taken as fact):

(continuity theorem): Let $\{u_n\}$ be probability measures with characteristic functions $\{φ_n\}$.(i) if $μ_n \rightarrow μ$ in distribution for some $μ$ then $φ_n(t)→ φ_∞(t)$ pointwise , where $φ_∞$ is the characteristic function of $μ$.(ii) Conversely, if $φ_n → φ$ pointwise for some $φ$ that is continuous at zero, then $μ_n → μ$ in distribution where $μ$ is a measure having characteristic function $φ$.

The question is as follows:

What happens when you apply the continuity theorem to the sequence of distributions $N(0,n)$?

I'm would guess that I should take the characteristic function of $N(0,n)$ and see what that converges to pointwise, but this characteristic function is $\exp\Big(\frac{-n^2t^2}{2}\Big)$, so I'm not really sure how this works because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\exp\Big(\frac{-n^2t^2}{2}\Big) = 0$. I'm also not sure whether or not this is the right approach. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi_{n}(t)\equiv\exp(-(nt)^{2}\,/\,2)$. Note that $\varphi_{n}(0)=1$
and $\varphi_{n}(t)\rightarrow0$ for all $t\neq0$. That is, $\varphi_{n}$
converges pointwise to a discontinuous function, and hence Levy's
continuity theorem does not apply.